# как правильнее: захожу или зайду?

Tags: выбор-слов

например когда вы  переходите улицу и увидите ваш друг
как правильнее сказать "сейчас захожу в магазин" или "сейчас зайду в магазин"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы переходите улицу и встречаете **своего друга**, то можно сказать и так, и так.

Ситуация первая. Вы в магазине еще **не были** и говорите:
«Сейчас зайду в магазин и куплю хлеба».

Ситуация вторая. Вы только что **были** в магазине и рассказываете другу:
« Сейчас захожу в магазин, а хлеба нет. Представляешь?»

Comment: можно сказать "заходил" во втром случае?

Comment: Если  «сейчас», то лучше « зашёл».